# ActiveRecord, order objects based on JSON datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Just learning about JSON datatypes, wondering if there's a wonderful shortcut Rails has created to do some ordering. Suppose I have

```
object_a.payload = { "category_1" => 2, "category_2" => 1 }
object_b.payload = { "category_1" => 1 }
object_c.payload = { "category_2" => 3, "category_3" => 4 }
```

I want to write something like this:

```
["category_1", "category_2", "category_3"].each do |cat|
  ordered_list = Object.where("payload->>'cat' != ?", nil).order(..on the values of the cat key..)
  puts "#{cat} = #{ordered_list}"
end

->
"category_1 = object_b, object_a"
"category_2 = object_a, object_c"
"category_3 = object_c"
```

2 challenges:

1. How do you interpolate `cat` in the `where` statement?
2. Don't know where to begin with ordering based on the values of the hash, for a given key, if present, in the payload

Can do this inefficiently (envisioning 2 statements, first being `Object.select { |o| o.payload[cat].present? }`) but looking to do it efficiently with `where` statements and hopefully only one statement

Comment: Try `Object.where("payload ->> ? IS NOT NULL", cat)` -- however `.order()` does not seem to support binding parameters to it, but interpolating manually is really an ugly workaround. PS: in SQL you would need f.ex. `ORDER BY payload -> 'category_1'` if `payload` is a `jsonb` column. For `json` you may need a cast: `ORDER BY CAST(payload ->> 'category_1' AS INTEGER)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot the `sort_by` function... so building off @pozs clarification of how to filter out nil, the answer would be:

```
["category_1", "category_2", "category_3"].each do |cat|
  relevant_items = Object.where("payload ->> ? IS NOT NULL", cat)
  ordered_list = relevant_items.sort_by { |i| i.payload[cat] }
  puts "#{cat} = #{ordered_list}"
end
```